# How to Pass Application URL through Command Line with Cucumber Feature file via cucumber options?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, command-line-arguments, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Currently we have 9 different URLs in our requirement scope and its implemented as Config file Application URL.
Every time if I have to change Application URL, I need to manually update the URL in config file and then I can execute require scenario, which is tedious task.

I would like to pass Application URL in my command line argument.

Current configuration of Config file.

```
#application.url=http://node-1.nginx.portal.da-1.can.qa.aws.com
#http://node-1.nginx.portal.da-1.QA1.aws.com
#http://node-1.nginx.portal.da-1.QA2.qa.aws.com
#http://node-1.nginx.portal.da-1.QA3.qa.aws.com
#http://node-1.nginx.portal.da-1.QA4.qa.aws.com
#http://node-1.nginx.portal.da-1.QA5.qa.aws.com
#http://node-1.nginx.portal.da-1.QA6.qa.aws.com
```

```
public void LaunchApplication() {
        LOG.info("Launching web application URL: " + CONFIG.getProperty("application.url"));
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.get(CONFIG.getProperty("application.url"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Gonna make the assumption that you are running your selenium cucumber tests as a maven project.

Using maven you can create as many maven system properties as you like, I do this a lot for my mvn commands for my CI/CD build pipelines using Jenkins.

Here is what I would do

1. Update your method by adding a system property variable:

   ```
   public void LaunchApplication() {
     String appUrl = System.getProperty(applicationUrl);

     LOG.info("Launching web application URL: " + appUrl);
     driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
     driver.get(appUrl);
   }
   ```
2. Pass the property as your mvn command, for example:
   `mvn test -Pcucumber -Dcucumber.options="--tags @app-smoke-001" -Dbrowser=chrome -Dclose_browser=yes -DapplicationUrl="http://node-1.nginx.portal.da-1.can.qa.aws.com"`

Comment: This. And if you have a bundle of urls all for the same environment, use different config files and provide the config file name as an environment parameter.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje - good shout, definitely a better suggestion of properties there

Comment: Can you give me reference of the same i.e Different properties file for different URL configurations?

I'm checking with the first suggestion provided by djmonki as mentioned above.

Will keep you posted.

Comment: @djmonki While trying to implement the way you suggested, getting URL as Null.

Can you please suggest a way to declaring variable over here, it seems I'm missing something over here.

public void LaunchApplication() {
  
  String applicationUrl = null;
  //String applicationUrl = null;
   String appUrl = System.getProperty(applicationUrl);

    LOG.info("Launching web application URL: " + appUrl);
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.get(appUrl);

}

Comment: Command: mvn test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/featureFiles/UserManager/UserManager.feature" -Dapplication.url="http://node-1.nginx.portal.da-1.can.qa.aws.net/login"

Comment: Getting NullPointerException.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: url=null
        at com.google.common.collect.CollectPreconditions.checkEntryNotNull(CollectPreconditions.java:32)

Comment: In your command you have decalred `Dapplication.url="node-1.nginx.portal.da-1.can.qa.aws.net/login"`, that should be declared as `Dapplication.url="http://node-1.nginx.portal.da-1.can.qa.aws.net/login"`, as per your original config file. Can you try that and see how you get on

Comment: @djmoki

Current Implementation: 

_public void LaunchApplication() { 
   String appUrl = System.getProperty("application.url");
    LOG.info("Launching web application URL: " + appUrl);
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.get(appUrl);
}_

**Command**

mvn test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/featureFiles/UserManager/UserManager.feature" -Dapplication.url="http://node-1.nginx.portal.da-1.can.qa.aws.net/login"


Still getting same NLP Exception.

Comment: I think you may have got confused with my comment, I believe you need to declare the url appended with http:// - so the mvn argument for the application url that you will pass on the command line is `Dapplication.url="http://node-1.nginx.portal.da-1.can.qa.aws.net/login"`

Comment: Ah my bad.!! but still getting NLP

I am passing whole URL with http only, when I am commenting over here- its changing unfortunately.

Comment: Just noticed in your method you have the following : `System.getProperty("application.url");`. Remove the quotes inside the bracket, so it becomes `System.getProperty(application.url);` and try again

Comment: Same behavior- NLP exception.
@M.P.Korstanje - Can you share your suggestions about different Environment configurations and pass that through command line?

Comment: Can you provide your full method, so we can understand where this is being passed: `com.google.common.collect.CollectPreconditions.checkEntryNotNull`

Comment: Thanks @djmonki- its resolved as per your answer.
Now- I'm looking for how to make utilize different configuration file, and pass the required environment through command line which will pointing out this configuration file and picking up URL from the configuration file.
Any idea and reference for the same?

Comment: @DhrumilSoni - well done, happy that it works. A bit busy today, but I can help out. If you can expand your original question above, by showing your method/class for the CONFIG properties file, then we can go from there